# Changing shapefile longitude from -180 - 180 to 0 - 360?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, ogr2ogr, extents, latitude-longitude

I have a shapefile of world countries, with longitude between -180° and 180°.
How can I change the shapefile (eg. with ogr2ogr) for having longitude between 0 and 360°.

Following OSGEO/Trac explanation about [GenParms](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms), I tried this without success (the result is still in -180 - 180:

> ogr2ogr -wrapdateline -t_srs '+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84
>   +lon_wrap=-180 +over' /data/tmp/new_algo/world_new.shp /data/tmp/new_algo/world.shp

I need to have the new longitude defined as:

> if Lon < 0:
>       new_Lon = 360 + Lon
>   else:
>       new_Lon = Lon

Of course, the process must take care of the date line.

Comment: Do you mean `if Lon < 0: new_Lon = 360 + Lon else: new_Lon = Lon`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need (sorry for my typo, I've edited it now). I saw your answer below, the problem is that everything is shifted, including the parts in 0-180 that should not move.

Comment: I've updated my answer in order to consider your last comment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using GDAL >= 1.10.0 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite:

```
ogr2ogr world_shifted.shp world.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoords(geometry,180,0) FROM world"
```

or:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +pm=-180 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" world_shifted.shp world.shp
```

Both commands produce a longitude offset of 180°, i.e. a prime meridian of -180° is considered. In fact:

```
>ogrinfo world_shifted.shp world_shifted | grep Extent
Extent: (0.000000, -90.000000) - (360.000000, 83.623596)
```

The difference between the two commands is that with a longitude offset (2nd try) data are simply reprojected using -180° as prime meridian, while shifting the coordinates geometries (1st try) are altered, even if the result is apparently the same.

**EDIT**
If there are *parts in 0-180 that should not move*, it's possible to adapt this working solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73164/22405

Clip the two parts:

```
ogr2ogr world_part1.shp world.shp -clipsrc -180 -90 0 90
ogr2ogr world_part2.shp world.shp -clipsrc 0 -90 180 90
```

Shift only the first part:

```
ogr2ogr world_part1_shifted.shp world_part1.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoords(geometry,360,0), CNTRY_NAME FROM world_part1"
```

Then, merge the second part and the first shifted:

```
ogr2ogr world_0_360_raw.shp world_part2.shp
ogr2ogr -update -append world_0_360_raw.shp world_part1_shifted.shp -nln world_0_360_raw
```

Finally, dissolve countries boundaries of `world_0_360_raw.shp` obtaining `world_0_360.shp` by country names. For instance:

```
ogr2ogr world_0_360.shp world_0_360_raw.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(Geometry), CNTRY_NAME FROM world_0_360_raw GROUP BY CNTRY_NAME"
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not what I meant: the command you gave shifts the values, while I want to have another longitude mapping domain: [0 360] instead of [-180, 180], which means that the map will be centered on 180° (in the pacific) instead of 0° (Greenwhich). So I guess the operation should include some modulo operator?

Comment: In fact, a longitude offset (2nd try) produce a mapping domain of [0 360] and data are simply reprojected using -180° as prime meridian. Instead, shifting the coordinates geometries (1st try) are altered, even if the result is apparently the same.

Comment: Yes, simple but perfectly working approach. Thanks! Now, I only need to figure out how to get ride of the vertical line (border between the two dissolved polygons) that remains after the dissolve operation.

Comment: Where? The last `ogr2ogr` command works fine for me. There are only some multipolygons which fall near 0° and 360°, after the dissolve operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the +lon_wrap parameter is not implemented in ogr2ogr.

See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.proj-4.devel/5131

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Proper-PROJ-settings-for-lat-long-td5592484.html

And if Frank W. says it is not you have to live with that ;-)

If you only want a map centered on the pacific, try a map projection with 180°E as center meridian:

[QGIS display world country shape files centered on pacific ocean using Robinson, Miller Cylindrical or other projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson)