# How to update polygon longitude if negative?

Tags: ogr2ogr, sqlite, latitude-longitude

I have a polygon, with longitude in [-180, 180], with 2 parts around the dateline.
I want to make a map centered on the date line.
My plane is to:
1./ update the longitude, so that if lon < 0 , lon=lon+360
2./ dissolve the two part to get a unique polygon.

My problem is now 1./
I'm trying:

```
ogr2ogr nodateline\new_polygons.shp org_polygon.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoords(geometry, 360, 0) FROM org_polygon WHERE X(geometry)<0"
```

and the command returns the following error:

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'ShiftCoords(geometry, 360, 0)' to 'ShiftCoord'
```

EDIT: I also tried with `ST_X(geometry)` instead of `X(geometry)`: same error.

The error only occur with the "WHERE" clause.
a./ what does the error mean?
b./ what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Does your ogr2ogr have spatialite support? (You can test this using ogr2ogr --formats) If not, what are you using to provide the spatial functions?

Comment: Note that it would be easier to work in a coordinate system centered on the dateline.

Comment: @radouxju: It looks like the data already exists, and Bruno knows to move it to a coordinate system centred on the dateline - the question asks "how".

Comment: It was just a comment, sorry if it was unclear. I don't know ogr2ogr so I don't have an answer to the question. However, I know from experience that working with "out of bound" coordinates (with the proposed equation, you could have Easting of 359°) is often a source of problem. My suggestion is to project the existing data to a custom crs with the origin near 180 (e.g. EPSG 5517).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to twist the data, but the map. See this tutorial on how to make pacific centered maps:

[QGIS display world country shape files centered on pacific ocean using Robinson, Miller Cylindrical or other projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson)

If your data is not across the whole world, you can leave out the split by polygon as mentioned there.

Comment: In principle, I'd agree with you. In this specific case, my problem is the dateline, that remain visible, because the polygons are split around it: once centering my openlyers view on the Pacific, the border of the polygons show the dateline, which I don't want.

Comment: Ok, in your case it would be best to transform the data to one of the projections I mentioned, and then join those polygons that are split by the +/-180° meridian. Otherwise you might get nasty effects if you want to reuse the data in "normal" projections afterwards.

Comment: Actually, I'm kind of swimming in circles: at the beginning, I wanted to go grom EPSG:4326 to another latlon/WGS84 with long in 0-360°, but get stuck because +lon_wrap is not supported (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79447). In your example i see different projections centered around Pacific, but nothing like a geodetic/WGS84. Would such a projection EPSG code exist?

Comment: Unless you use sqlite or postgis, you are not bound to existing EPSG codes.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning, not an error. In order to avoid it, you should normalize the field name adding `AS newfieldname` after `ShiftCoords(...)`, but it's not mandatory. Then, you should substitute `layer` with its real name (`org_polygon`) in the `SQL` statement (this was an error). So it should be:

```
ogr2ogr nodateline\new_polygons.shp org_polygon.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoords(geometry, 360, 0), * FROM org_polygon WHERE X(geometry)<0"
```

However, `X(geometry)` is not suitable for polygon geometries, but for point ones. I'd use a clipping approach, like in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/79448/22405

Comment: by "layer" I meant the layer name. I edit my post in that sense, but the error message is still the same.

Comment: I've updated the SQL statement. There was a `*` missing.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still answer the same error message. I replaced X(geometry) with ST_X(geometry): same error message too.

Comment: Because `X( pt Point ) : Double precision` (Source: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html#p5)