# Reproject vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, polygon, web-mapping, proj

I want to warp a vector layer (set of polygons, but not a raster map) to fit a map. The problem is, the vector layer coordinates are from 0 to 360 and the basemap layer coordinates are from -180 to 180

[image: My initial status]

So I tried subtracting -360 from polygon coordinates, but polygons are broken (maybe because of meridian)

[image: My problem]

Eventually what I want is this picture, (just for description, I duplicated the layer). Can somebody help please?

The polygon file is GeoJSON.

[image: This is what I want to make]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79447/how-to-change-shapefile-longitude-from-180-180-to-0-360