# QGIS map wraparound in WGS84

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I am learning QGIS.

I'm working with the 'Natural_Earth_quick_start' data set from the tutorials. The WGS84 projection gives me the view I want. However, this looks like a sheet of paper, and on the right hand side the ocean ends just after Suva, Funafuti, and further to the right I see only white space. Of course, if I move all the way to the left of the map, I see the continuation of the ocean (and places like Nukualofa, Apia). Since all these places are of interest to me, I would like to center my map so it wrap around somewhere else (say middle of the continental US), so that I can see these four places in a single view (Suva, Funafuti, Nukualofa, Apia).

How I can do this while remaining in the WGS84 projection?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to specify the exact version of software in use within each question.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson @Vince?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe not in the question, but the answers should certainly be reviewed

Comment: when setting a new projection center artefacts can occur: to avoid this take a look at these posts:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72621/how-to-render-area-that-crosses-180
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99571/how-to-dissolve-naturalearth-vectordata-with-gdal