# Convert shapefiles from WGS84 to Miller Projection

Tags: shapefile, convert, ogr2ogr

I have some shapefiles of the world from Natural Earth at **WGS84**.  I would like to convert them to the **Miller Projection**.  I have **ogr2ogr**, but I'm not sure what the parameters  for this conversion should be, or if this conversion can be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the eastern part of Russia crosses the 180° meridian, you have to cut your shapefile there. I have written a tutorial for cutting at any meridian to use the Natural Earth shapefiles here:

[QGIS display world country shape files centered on pacific ocean using Robinson, Miller Cylindrical or other projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson)

The clipping polygon for your case is:

```
Nr;WKT
1;POLYGON ((180.1 90, 179.9 90, 179.9 -90, 180.1 -90, 180.1 90))
```

giving you this result with EPSG:53003 (the spherical version of the Miller projection):

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If this works in QGIS, it works as well with pure ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrclayer D:\Karten\shp\Projektionen\180deg.txt -t_srs EPSG:53003 D:\Karten\shp\Projektionen\ne-miller.shp D:\Karten\shp\NaturalEarth\ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

Test if target srs epsg:54003 gives correct result. You can check with some coordinates with gdaltransform first:

```
>gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:54003
20 40
2223901.03956182 4674067.69647085 -1662.3178422926
```

Comment: It works, but it gets all weird at the edges, particularly in Russia, Alaska, Fiji, etc.  Horizontal lines from edge to edge appear.  Would that be fixable?

Comment: Sorry, too technical thing for me. Perhaps mail to gdal-dev mailing list could help. Attach your command and link to source data and screen capture from the wierd result.

Comment: @user30184 : have you taken a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72621/how-to-render-area-that-crosses-180%C2%B0 ? does your problem look like the maps here?