# Polygons (world countries) over 180 degrees gets broken in rendering

Tags: carto

I have a table with world country polygons, and some polygons (as in real life) cross 180 degree longitude line, so they have both 179... and -179... coordinates.

1. As long as it is in PostGIS or exported to Shapefile, then it is displayed ok in QGIS.
2. Problem 1: When I converted it to GeoJSON, then it got broken, and geojson.io and QGIS both shows it broken. See image below
3. Problem 2: When I imported GeoJSON or Shapefile to CartoDB, then it was broken also. I suspect CartoDB does internal conversion to GeoJSON which distorts it.

My ultimate goal is to get it working in CartoDB, so it is rendered correctly. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the answers to this questions can help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72621/how-to-render-area-that-crosses-180%C2%B0

Comment: Well, the problem and errors in rendering look similar indeed. But here I don't really want to change hemisphere rendering or anything in rendering  - just to understand why rendering in QGIS from PostGIS and Shapefile are ok, but once GeoJSON is involved (or CartoDB) then rendering breaks. Projection remains always the same (Spherical Mercator). Of course I'd need a way to fix it also, otherwise I can't use CartoDB for particular use case.