# How to reproject world raster from wgs84 to World Miller Cylindrical (EPSG 54003) and keep New Zealand?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have a world raster in WGS84, downloaded from Natural Earth. When I set projection to World Miller Cylindrical (EPSG 54003) I lose parts of New Zealand as you can see in the attached pictures. Is there any way to solve this problem in QGIS (version 2.8 or 3)?

[image: wgs84][image: miller]

Comment: Its ESRI 54003, not EPSG. Not sure it has an EPSG code, but can be done with a proj4 string: http://proj4.org/projections/mill.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, proj +proj=mill +lon_0=0 gives the same result (54003 actually has the same definition)

https://epsg.io/54003

Comment: If others can reproject cleanly to Miller with the same QGIS version, it could be a data-specific issue. What are the extents of the original raster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution using gdalwarp. Here is how I solved it:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:53003 -of GTiff "C:/Users/Zoran/Desktop/input.tif" "C:/Users/Zoran/Desktop/output.tif" -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000
```

The key is using **-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000**

*SOURCE_EXTRA: This is a number of extra pixels added around the source window for a given request, and by default it is 1 to take care of rounding error. Setting this larger will increase the amount of data that needs to be read, but can avoid missing source data.* http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html

[image]

Someone may experience similar problem with vector data. It can be solved using Antonio Falciano answer: [How to render area that crosses 180°?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72621/how-to-render-area-that-crosses-180)

Answer (score 2):

If I create a custom projection in QGIS with this string `"+proj=mill +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R_A +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"` I get a nice map with NZ:

[image]

If I switch to "EPSG:54003" (and I don't know why QGIS thinks its an EPSG code....) I get NZ chopped:

[image]

You can see all of NZ with EPSG:54003 if you zoom in and pan a bit, but there's some weird cropping going on. But set as a custom CRS as I've given, it seems to work fine. This is QGIS 3 with Proj4 version 493.

Comment: I am still getting the same result, and I am using the same version of QGIS and Proj4 as you...

Comment: It might help if you take the sphere version of Miller, EPSG:53003. Apart from that, try to save in that CRS, instead of using on-the-fly reprojection.

Comment: @AndreJ Tried sphere version and saving everything but the same problem persists...