# Reprojecting Natural Earth dataset to World Eckert I

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, natural-earth

My question is connected with QGIS 2. Could anybody explain me how I ought to reproject the Natural Earth dataset there in order my world map to look correctly? When I strive to reproject these data I get the result that you can see on the image below.

I was using the next parameters for my projection:

```
+proj=eck1 +lon_0=120 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

That is a modified "World Eckert I" projection.

[image: Figure 1. Natural Earth dataset after reprojecting]

Comment: Looks like your vertices cross the +/- 180 degree meridians - related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41827/how-to-build-a-minimum-convex-hull-crossing-the-180-degrees-line

Comment: @Mapperz: Not the 180° degree, but 60°W as the antipodial meridian to the chosen projection causes the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to split up your world at 60° West (or better between -60.1° and -59.9° East) to avoid those artefacts of polygon filling, if you center at 120° East.

- Change **project** CRS to EPSG:4326
- Create a text file with the following content:

> ```
>  Nr;WKT
>  1;POLYGON((-60.1 100, -59.9 100, -59.9 -100, -60.1 -100, -60.1 100))
> ```

- Import it as delimited text with semicolon as delimiter and EPSG:4326 as CRS
- Perform `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Difference` on the ne_10m_land to a new shapefile
- Remove the ne_10m_land and the polygon around -60° layers from the canvas
- change project CRS to Eckert I

And your map will look like this:

[image]