# Polygons get stretched all over the map when changing CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to change the CRS of a vector layer in QGIS, but the output seems to be deformed.

As you can see from the attached pictures, some of the points belonging to polygons which are situated near the edges of the map in the input layer get wrapped on the other side of the world in the reprojected layer. I also wish to point out that I'm properly using "save as...", and not "set layer CRS".

Can anybody explain why is this happening? Is it because, as I suspect, some points are exactly on 180 longitude and not, for instance, 179.999?

Is there is a way to correct the problem (possibly without manually editing each problematic point)?

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212055/reprojection-causes-polygon-to-stretch-across-globe?rq=1). After using GDAL "clip by extent" to -180 < x  <180 and -90    <y  <90, there is no more stretching.

In the sidebar I saw a solution to a similar problem. I had used the search tool before asking, but apparently my query wasn't good enough...